# What elements accept flow content?

Tags: html

I can easily find a [list of elements that are considered being "Flow content"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content), it's most of them. What I can't find is a list of the elements that **accept** flow content as their content.

What is the list of those elements?